# How does one refactor defineComponent using nuxt bridge?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-bridge

I am trying to migrate my nuxt 2 project to nuxt 3. My Nuxt 2 project uses the [composition api](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/). I am using [nuxt bridge](https://nuxt.com/docs/bridge/overview) to make the transition easier.

Through the composition API, I have been creating every component with `defineComponent`:

```
import { defineComponent, computed } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
```

I've looked through the nuxt bridge documentation, and it's unclear how to refactor `defineComponent`. Does anyone know how I should refactor `defineComponent`? Do I continue using `defineComponent` but instead import it from '#imports' as described [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/bridge/nuxt3-compatible-api#explicit-imports)? If so, does this mean that my change would look like this?

```
import { defineComponent } from '#imports'
```

Comment: Nuxt 3 offers built-in support for the Vue.js 3 Composition API. To make the transition, you can simply replace the usage of defineComponent with the new script setup syntax. Could you provide some code snippet maybe that can help refactor to Nuxt 3 without the `defineComponent`